# journalctl giving "unsupported feature" error

Tags: systemd-journald

A simple `journalctl` command is now giving me this error

```
Journal file /var/log/journal/ad9213e031ec2a16399a42515988884e/user-1001@ae426ac82df44a8489f745ad63e8c9ea-000000000000215f-0005848bb1ab0334.journal uses an unsupported feature, ignoring file.
Use SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug journalctl --file=/var/log/journal/ad9213e031ec2a16399a42515988884e/user-1001@ae426ac82df44a8489f745ad63e8c9ea-000000000000215f-0005848bb1ab0334.journal to see the details.
-- No entries --
```

When I invoke the recommended command `SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug journalctl --file=/var/log/journal/ad9213e031ec2a16399a42515988884e/user-1001@ae426ac82df44a8489f745ad63e8c9ea-000000000000215f-0005848bb1ab0334.journal` I get

```
Journal effective settings seal=no compress=no compress_threshold_bytes=8B
Journal file /var/log/journal/ad9213e031ec2a16399a42515988884e/user-1001@ae426ac82df44a8489f745ad63e8c9ea-000000000000215f-0005848bb1ab0334.journal uses incompatible flag lz4-compressed disabled at compilation time.
Failed to open journal file /var/log/journal/ad9213e031ec2a16399a42515988884e/user-1001@ae426ac82df44a8489f745ad63e8c9ea-000000000000215f-0005848bb1ab0334.journal: Protocol not supported
mmap cache statistics: 0 hit, 1 miss
Failed to open files: Protocol not supported
```

`journalctl --version` gives

```
systemd 244 (244)
-PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT -GNUTLS -ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS -KMOD -IDN2 -IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified
```

It looks like someone on redhat with the same version is having [the same problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1778809)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have noticed the error in what I wrote in my question, but as a tolerant admin on the Ubuntu bug tracker pointed out, systemd version 244 is ahead of Ubuntu's version 237 for 18.04. Turns out that [homebrew](http://brew.sh) installs its own systemd and journalctl for certain packages and a recent upgrade introduced the error. **The new `journalctl` couldn't read journals that had been compressed with lz4, which is the default on Ubuntu**. To enable this, `journalctl` needs to be built with the flag `-Dlz4=true`. I submitted a patch to homebrew so that it works now.