# How to fix systemctl status not working as non-root user in 20.04 upgrade?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, systemd

I saw [this discussion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2443303) indicating others have seen this as well. I also recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. The symptom is this:

```
$ systemctl status networking
Failed to parse bus message: No such device or address
$ systemctl --user status valheim
Failed to parse bus message: No such device or address
```

However, a plain `systemctl status` works.

Also, if I run as root, querying a particular service, it works:

```
$ sudo systemctl status networking
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2021-03-28 22:39:17 EDT; 1 day 16h ago
```

Comment: possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208184/journalctl-giving-unsupported-feature-error